# Subtracting Step Functions in R

Tags: r, function

I have created two vectors of step functions, and I want to find the difference between the step functions corresponding to each index in the vector. I am using the MosaicCalc library in order to create the cumulative distribution functions grouped by election year, and I would like to subtract one set of functions from another set. Specifically, I create two vectors of step functions using the same data frame:

```
party_econ_cdf <- lapply(split(econ_spectrum_data, econ_spectrum_data$election), function(x) (antiD(stepfun(c(x$econ_place), c(x$econ_share.party, 0))(y) ~ y)))

voter_econ_cdf <- lapply(split(econ_spectrum_data, econ_spectrum_data$election), function(x) (antiD(stepfun(c(x$econ_place), c(x$econ_share.voter, 0))(y) ~ y)))
```

Ideally, I would like to calculate the difference as follows, but I cannot "subtract non-numeric arguments":

```
party_econ_cdf - voter_econ_cdf
```

Here is an overview of the CDF objects:

```
> dput(head(party_econ_cdf, 20))
list(`Albania, 2001` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Albania, 2005` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Albania, 2009` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Albania, 2013` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Albania, 2017` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Algeria, 2002` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Algeria, 2007` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Algeria, 2012` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Algeria, 2017` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2001` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2003` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2005` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2013` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2015` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2017` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2019` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Armenia, 2003` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Armenia, 2007` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Armenia, 2012` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Armenia, 2017` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)


> dput(head(voter_econ_cdf, 20))
list(`Albania, 2001` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Albania, 2005` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Albania, 2009` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Albania, 2013` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Albania, 2017` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Algeria, 2002` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Algeria, 2007` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Algeria, 2012` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Algeria, 2017` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2001` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2003` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2005` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2013` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2015` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2017` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Argentina, 2019` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Armenia, 2003` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Armenia, 2007` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Armenia, 2012` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
}, `Armenia, 2017` = function (y, C = 0) 
{
    numerical_integration(.newf, .wrt, as.list(match.call())[-1], 
        formals(), from, ciName = intC, .tol)
```

Comment: You need to supply a cut-paste example. We con't have any of these objects. If the range of these stepfunctions are not the same then you also need to specigy what values to use outside the extremes.

Comment: My code is extremely long, so I added a snapshot of the relevant data frame.

Comment: Pictures of data are worse than useless. You were hopefully not expecting us to re-create such data by re-entering it, right?

Comment: Is there a way for me to attach my code?

Comment: Do a search in SO for "great R reproducible example"

Comment: You should post the output of `dput(party_econ_cdf)` or, if it's too big, the output of `dput(head(party_econ_cdf, 20))` in the question. And the same for the other object, `voter_econ_cdf`. There's no need for the entire code that produced them or the entire data set `econ_spectrum_data`.